# Advantages to using Splunk Universal Forwarders or Splunk REST API?

Tags: java, rest, logging, splunk

I'm currently using Splunk as a way to index generated log files from a Java application. I have a Splunk Enterprise instance running using development data (on a local server), and currently the log data is just being pushed to Splunk via their REST API (using their Java SDK).

However, this Java app will eventually be used against production data, live on AWS EC2 instances. I'm wondering if there's any advantages to ditching their REST API and implementing [Splunk Universal Forwarders](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Forwarding/Introducingtheuniversalforwarder) on these EC2 instances.

**Would there be any advantages? When is it appropriate to use forwarders instead of the REST API?**

From what I can gather, the forwarders do well at scale, so perhaps this is an advantage? I've searched around but didn't find any clear-cut comparisons between the two, so I was hoping someone on here would perhaps have a better idea.

Comment: Take a look on http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.1/Forwarding/Typesofforwarders, the table of `Forwarder comparison`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splunk REST API is really meant for integration with external apps and requests to manage the already indexed data.

Any serious volume coming in should be handled by the Universal/Heavy Forwarders as they were purposely developed for that function (thus orders of magnitude more efficient).

Comment: While this is a really old question and the answer was correct at the time, I thought it would be worth updating by saying you could also use Splunk's Http Event Collector (HEC).

Originally designed as an option to get logs from mobile applications, the HEC is highly optimized, is designed to be ran behind a load balancer (removing single points of failure), and has a fairly simple and flexible options including sending in batches so it would be a good option to consider for new deployments.